# Redirecting user to a page when there is no content?

Tags: posts

```
else:
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
```

In the home.php file (my blog index), users are redirected to this template when there are no posts. In terms of syntax, does this code mean that the template the user is redirected to is content-none.php?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );` will look for:

```
 1.content-none.php
 2.content.php
```